# Question about basis of $\text{Der}_{k}(k[X])$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, derivations

Let $k[X] = k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ be the polynomial ring over a field of characteristic zero.

Assume that $(D_1,\ldots, D_n)$ is a $k[X]$-basis of $\text{Der}_k(k[X])$. Suppose that the vector space $\left<1, x_1,\ldots, x_n\right>$ is invariant by each $D_i$. Define $M_i = D_i|_{\left<1, x_1,\ldots, x_n\right>}$ and let $\left<M_1,\ldots, M_n\right>$ consists of nilpotent linear operators on $\left<1, x_1,\ldots, x_n\right>$.

Is it true that $\left<M_1,\ldots, M_n\right>^k = 0$ for some $k$?

Comment: Does $\langle\rangle$ mean $k$-linear span, ideal generated over $k[X]$, or something else?

Comment: It means $k$-linear span

Comment: Do you know an example where this happens and the change-of-basis matrix from the standard basis $(\partial_1, \dotsc, \partial_n)$ is not scalar?

Comment: $\partial_x$, $x\partial_y + \partial_z$ and $\partial_z$ in $k[x, y, z]$.

Comment: I edited the question. The previous one was not true beacuse we can consider $(\partial_x,\partial_y,y\partial_x+\partial_z,x\partial_y+\partial_t)$-basis of $\text{Der}_k(k[x, y, z, t])$

Comment: I don't understand the question as it stands.  Is there now a new assumption that the $k$-linear span $\langle M_1, \dotsc, M_n\rangle$ consists entirely of nilpotent operators?  Then you've got a collection of nilpotent operators on an $(n + 1)$-dimensional space, so $\langle M_1, \dotsc, M_n\rangle^{n + 1}$ equals $0$.  Or do you mean that $\langle M_1, \dotsc, M_n\rangle$ is defined to be the collection of nilpotent operators in the span?

Comment: I'm sorry!  I seem to have been [thinking](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368939/question-about-basis-of-textder-kkx#comment931294_368939) of the statement that a *Lie algebra* of nilpotent endomorphisms of a f.d. space behaves this way ([Engel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel%27s_theorem)).  I don't know the statement for mere vector spaces of endomorphisms, and agree it's probably not true in that generality.